# Speed Up AWS S3 Video Upload: Cloudfront or Transfer acceleration?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-sdk, amazon-cloudfront

I am uploading videos directly to a AWS S3 bucket, but the uploads seem slow for even a 10 second iPhone video. A user on my website uploads a video.

Step 1: Create createPresignedPost on server

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
s3 = new AWS.S3({apiVersion: '2006-03-01'});
AWS.config.update({keys, region});
var params = {
  Bucket: 'bucket',
  Fields: {
    key: fileNameKey
  },
  Expires: expireTime,
        Conditions: [
            ["content-length-range", 0, 500000000], // limit to 500 Mb
            [ "eq", "$acl", "public-read" ]
        ]
};
```

This works fine, I send the presignedPostUrl back to user browser, then the user uploads a file from the browser. Step 2:

```
let config = { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' } };
await axios.post(presignedPostUrl, formData, config)
```

And the video uploads fine, it's just slow. 26 seconds for a 60-second video. I tried enabled [AWS s3 Transfer acceleration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/enable-transfer-acceleration.html) in the AWS console, and then I initialize it when I create my presignedPostUrl in step 1:

```
s3 = new AWS.S3({useAccelerateEndpoint: true, apiVersion: '2006-03-01'});
```

Video uploads, but it's about the same speed as the original upload. 60 second iPhone video takes 30 seconds to upload.

Am I setting this up correctly? Would it be faster to upload using Cloudfront?

Answer (score 0):

AWS docs say that for files smaller than 1GB it's better to use Amazon CloudFront's PUT/POST instead of S3 Transfer Acceleration.